# Run a 400V apparatus using two 240V lines

Tags: voltage, mains, three-phase

I moved in to a rental home that only has 240 VAC available. Now I am faced with the task of connecting a sauna that ran on 340 V+ and an older 3 phase motor that was used for some hobby gear.

I have heard rumors that it is possible to run two 240v lines in series to make this happen. I am in Germany if that is needed information.

Comment: Sounds scary.  If the sauna ran on 340 Vac why would you hook 480 Vac up to it?  Do they have residential three phase power in Germany?

Comment: Yes, I can pay the 1000 euros it would take to bring in a line. But since this is a rental the cash would probably be better used (cheaper) to purchase 240vac equipment. I am just chasing down this rumor and exploring the options.

Comment: I don't know how you'd "put two 240V lines in series" without having the electric utility wire them that way for you. If your 3-phase power distribution system has 240V phase-to-neutral (Y configuration), then the phase-to-phase voltage will be 416V. Any other voltage will have to be gotten via a transformer of some sort.

Comment: If you can find a surplus dealer that buys excess stock from electrical contractors, you might be able to obtain a cheap transformer that lowers your cost to add 3ph. Then you could discuss getting a one time rent abatement for improving the property with the landlord.

Comment: For the three phase equipment you can use the inertia of a larger idler motor connected in electrical parallel and started up somehow (phase shift cap) as a rotary phase converter - used to have a lathe setup like that.  Today getting a VFD which rectifies the available inputs to DC and then synthesizes 3 phases at adjustable frequency is also an option - the manufacturer can tell you the power derating when used with only two inputs.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll use a single phase 5hp 240v motor I got from ebay for now and see if I can get a good trade or sale for the 12hp monster later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that there were 340V systems around on this planet.

Europe, including Germany has 400V 3Ph+N or 230V 1Ph+N power supply connections for domestic use. In some EU countries older pre-WWII estates still have 3-Ph 230V without neutral grids.

Connecting a 340V system is impossible. You could make use of a transformer but that will be a costly affair for a sauna. Then there's always a power limitation. No idea what the consumption of that sauna is but in Germany a standard connection generally has a limitation of 63A (14,5 kVA) for a single phase connection and 35A for a three phase connection.

Comment: Thanks, this is the info I was looking for to make an assessment of the risk involved in not doing things correctly.  This is the thing here in Berlin. Because many are from the East they have gotten used to making things work. There are still many appliances and buildings using pre-war electricals. I am quite surprised that there are not more electrical fires around.

Answer (score 0):

Europe uses 3 phase wye 220V/380V 4 wire system. (3 phases and a neutral)
Line to neutral is 220V, line to line 380V.
The house may not have 380V outlet, but the voltage may be coming to the house.
I would recommend getting a qualified help with that.